C++ 2D array types
I am trying to drive a Neopixel strip from a 16MHz 5V Adafruit Trinket
I have a button to cycle around off, white, red, green & blue, so I want to store those five options as RGB values
In my code, I have (I've snipped out the irrelevant parts)
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip(PIXEL_COUNT, PIXEL_PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);
...
//colour array (OFF/WHITE/RED/GREEN/BLUE)
uint16_t colour[5][3]{ {0,0,0}, {255,255,255}, {255,0,0}, {0,255,0}, {0,0,255}};

Is uint16_t the right array type for the colour[5][3] array?
Then a function that's called via callbacks, when the pixels need a colour or brightness change
void renewStrip(float b, int c){ //b=brightness factor from 0.1 to 1 & c = index to colour array, containing colour RGB values
  for (int pixel = 0; pixel < strip.numPixels(); pixel++){
    // strip.Colour(R,G,B) converts the three uint8_t or uint16_t (I tried both?) RGB values in the indexed colour array into a combined colour value for strip.Color
    strip.setPixelColor(pixel, strip.Color(colour[c][1]*b,colour[c][2]*b,colour[c][3]*b));
  }
  strip.show();
}

Setup has the following
void setup() {
...
  strip.begin();           // INITIALIZE NeoPixel strip object (REQUIRED)
  strip.show();            // Turn OFF all pixels ASAP
  //strip.setBrightness(50); // Set BRIGHTNESS to about 1/5 (max = 255)
}

I presume that when I call on the array, with strip.Color(colour[c][1],colour[c][1],colour[c][1]), the colour array will return the r, g & b values into the Neopixel.Color method that will generate a uint32_t combined r, g & b value that can be consumed correctly by the second parameter of the Neopixel.setPixelColor method?
Are my presumptions correct? Is there a better approach? Types in multidimentional arrays - what's going on?

Your chief mistake is thinking that arrays start at 1, but the first index is 0. So strip.Color(colour[c][0]*b,colour[c][1]*b,colour[c][2]*b). You seem to understand this for the first dimension [c] but have forgotten it for the second.

As for the correct type, since you are multiplying all the colour values by a float factor b then the sensible type for me would also be float. You could also make an argument for uint8_t since your colour values are in that range. uint16_t isn't wrong, but it's not a natural choice as far as I can see.

Yup, hands up to the first one - schoolboy error - I knew that but just made an unforced error. Thanks for spotting it.

I was toying with the idea that I should cast the float brightness factor * R/G/B value (0-255 value) back to an integer

I stripped out all the superfluous code and coded a gradual build up by generating the uint8_t values for each component colour, before I used it in the strip.Color() method. To my mind, it's easier to surface each step and be sure of the input and output types
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#include <EasyButton.h>
//#include <avr/sleep.h>
#ifdef __AVR__
 #include <avr/power.h> // Required for 16 MHz Adafruit Trinket
#endif

#define COLOR_BUTTON_PIN   0 // button to cycle through OFF/WHITE/RED/GREEN/BLUE
#define BRIGHTNESS_BUTTON_PIN   1 // button to increment brightness factor from 0.1 to 1 in increments of 0.1 
#define PIXEL_PIN    2  // Digital IO pin connected to the NeoPixels.
#define PIXEL_COUNT 29  // Number of NeoPixels

// Buttons.
EasyButton COLOR_BUTTON(COLOR_BUTTON_PIN);
EasyButton BRIGHTNESS_BUTTON(BRIGHTNESS_BUTTON_PIN);

Adafruit_NeoPixel strip(PIXEL_COUNT, PIXEL_PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

// button variables
float   bright        = 0.1;  // brightness factor
int     col           = 0;    // Currently-active colour index on colour array (of lightCol objects)

//colour array (OFF/WHITE/RED/GREEN/BLUE)
uint16_t colour[5][3]{ {0,0,0}, {255,255,255}, {255,0,0}, {0,255,0}, {0,0,255}};

void renewStrip(float b, int c){ //b=brightness factor from 0.1 to 1 & c = index to colour array, containing colour objects (RGB values)
  uint8_t red   = static_cast<int>(colour[c][0]*b);
  uint8_t green = static_cast<int>(colour[c][1]*b);
  uint8_t blue  = static_cast<int>(colour[c][2]*b);

  for (int pixel = 0; pixel < strip.numPixels(); pixel++) {
// strip.Colour(R,G,B) converts the three uint8_t RGB values in the indexed colour array into a combined colour value for strip.Color
    strip.setPixelColor(pixel, strip.Color(red,green,blue));
  }
  strip.show();
}

void setup() {
  // These lines are specifically to support the Adafruit Trinket 5V 16 MHz.
  // Any other board, you can remove this part (but no harm leaving it):
  #if defined(__AVR_ATtiny85__) && (F_CPU == 16000000)
    clock_prescale_set(clock_div_1);
  #endif
  strip.begin();           // INITIALIZE NeoPixel strip object (REQUIRED)
  strip.show();            // Turn OFF all pixels ASAP
  //strip.setBrightness(50); // Set BRIGHTNESS to about 1/5 (max = 255)
  renewStrip(0.1, 1);
}

void loop(){
  delay(500000);
}

